# в latex заголовок раздела остаётся последней строкой на предыдущей странице

Tags: latex

Имею текст, и хочу чтобы заголовки (Надпись 1-Х в примере) не были на последней странице. Текст не разбит на секции или иные какие деления, просто идёт сплошняком:

```
Надпись 1
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк

Надпись 2
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
--разрыв страницы--
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
...
...
...
надпись Х
--разрыв страницы--
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
текст на несколько строк
```

Comment: Так может надо разбить? А то как он должен догадаться что это заголовок?

Comment: ну даже и разобью, он перестанет заголовки оставлять на прошлой странице?

Comment: Ну вообще в стандартном оформлении есть запрет «висячих» заголовоков (хотя возможно в стандартном оформлении они просто всегда с новой страницы начинаются).

Ещё в принципе есть LaTeX-овская команда `\nolinebreak`.

Но вообще неплохо бы показать основную часть документа. Потому что в вашем примере нет LaTeX-а.